# What Technologies Is Google Wave Using?

Tags: google-wave

What are the technologies employed in building Google Wave?

**Edit**: I have moved and amalgamated the answers into an answer below, rather than here in the question where they were.

Answer (score 12):

- Real-time editing - some kind of Ajax/Comet for server side calls.
- Version-control.
- Built in Google Web Toolkit (GWT).

  - GWT involves Java, Javascript, CSS, HTML.
- Custom built protocol. Wave protocol.

  - Uses the xmmp standard
- Rich text-editor.
- Language translation.
- Google Gears, for drag and drop (of files) functionality. Trying to get it into the HTML5 spec.

Answer (score 4):

It's using HTML5 for the interface and XMPP (Jabber's protocol) for the communication stuff.

Answer (score 3):

The revolutionary part is [Operational Transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operational_transformation).  Based on the [Jupiter collaborative system](http://portal.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=215585.215706).

You may like to watch this video: [Google I/O 2009 - Google Wave Under the hood](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uOFzWZrsPV0)

Answer (score 0):

I believe Google Wave is built on HTML5.

Comment: Which HTML5 technologies?

- Offline storage.
- Geolocation?
- Canvas?
- Multithreading/processes?

Comment: (One) better question may be: what technologies does the new version of GWT use/require. It looks like the demo runs on Chrome, Safari 4, and Firefox 3.5(?) so perhaps HTML 5 and canvas are baseline requirements. Will IE 8 work?

Answer (score 0):

I understand that they use an Extension to the Jabber protocol for the federated wave servers.

The realtime editing is based on an algorithm sometimes called jupiter algorithm and described in [this paper](http://ftp//ftp.lambda.moo.mud.org/pub/papers/JupiterWin.ps). More informations can be found on http://www.waveprotocol.org/whitepapers